# BLE oncharacteristicchanged not called in android 4.4 and 5

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

i have a program that send a word to ble and get some data . in android 6 and 7 it works well. but in android 4.4 and 5 the oncharacteristicchanged   not called after writeCharacteristic. i add a delay between enable notifications and writeCharacteristic but not worked. 
enable notification code:

```
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar,true);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(CCCD);
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
```

the uuids are :

```
    CCCD            = UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    RX_SERVICE_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001234-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    RX_CHAR_UUID    = UUID.fromString("00001235-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
    TX_CHAR_UUID    = UUID.fromString("00001236-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
```

this is logcat

```
    03-14 11:29:10.024 11767-12038/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothGatt: onGetCharacteristic() - Device=E3:84:5F:81:55:87 UUID=00001236-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
03-14 11:29:10.029 11767-11779/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothGatt: onGetDescriptor() - Device=E3:84:5F:81:55:87 UUID=00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
03-14 11:29:10.029 11767-11778/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothGatt: onSearchComplete() = Device=E3:84:5F:81:55:87 Status=0
03-14 11:29:10.029 11767-11778/com.example.metasense D/onServicesDiscovered bt: onServicesDiscovered
03-14 11:29:10.029 11767-11778/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothService: mBluetoothGatt = android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@42c448d8
03-14 11:29:10.029 11767-11778/com.example.metasense D/enableTXNotification bt: enableTXNotification
03-14 11:29:10.029 11767-11778/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00001236-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: true
03-14 11:29:10.029 11767-11778/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothGatt: writeDescriptor() - uuid: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
03-14 11:29:10.334 11767-11778/com.example.metasense D/writeRXChar bt: writeRXCharacteristic
03-14 11:29:10.334 11767-12258/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothService: mBluetoothGatt null (1/1) android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@42c448d8
03-14 11:29:10.334 11767-12258/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothGatt: writeCharacteristic() - uuid: 00001235-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
03-14 11:29:10.334 11767-12258/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothService: All1packs sent.
03-14 11:29:10.394 11767-12258/com.example.metasense D/akhare write bt: inja
03-14 11:29:10.404 11767-12038/com.example.metasense D/BluetoothGatt: onDescriptorWrite() - Device=E3:84:5F:81:55:87 UUID=00001236-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
03-14 11:29:13.454 11767-11794/com.example.metasense V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

the Bluetooth madule is nRF51822. please help me...

Comment: You need to add more details. We cannot know why your peripheral doesn't send the expected data. Have you debugged anything. Like checking peripheral log, sniffer trace, hci log or logcat?

Comment: thanks. i add the logcat

Answer (score 0):

So I assume if you have already been using the Nordic UartService.java sample code from the git repo. Do this in your UartService.java.
For some weird reason Android was unstable in reading the data available and I have managed to reliable reads by reading multiple times at different spots.

This will be in your gatt callback method in UartService.java

```
@Override
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,  
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {

super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);


//Check to verify whether gatt is successful and you're reading the right characterstic

if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS &&
                    characteristic.getUuid().equals(TX_CHAR_UUID)) {

                //Your byte[] will be extracted here if available
                byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();

                //Update to tell data is available
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);

                //No data
                if (data == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead: data = null ERROR???");

                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED);

                    return;
                }


            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead" + status);
            }




            }
```

In the same UartService.java add the following method

```
public void readData(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
        gatt.readCharacteristic(c);
    }
```

In your enableTXNotification do this

```
mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar,true);
BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(CCCD);
descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);


//Delay based on recommendations from various blog posts 

        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


//Now call readData method
        readData(mBluetoothGatt,TxChar);
```

Despite inefficiencies present in both Android and nRF51822 module, reading multiple times helped me capture data even though if it failed/missed the first time. Try this and let me know if it helps. This works on my Android OS 5.1, 6.0 and 7.
Make sure you request ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION/ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permissions both in the manifest and also dynamically during runtime for 6.0 and 7. Refer google sample code for this.